# Cannot access wordpress blog admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, admin, panel

i cannot access my wordpress blog admin panel for site http://www.abadhotels.com/blog/ The admin panel was accessible before. now when i try to access the admin panel instead of redirecting to the login page its shows a message "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/abadhote/public_html/blog/wp-includes/category-template.php:1) in /home/abadhote/public_html/blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207"
i tried to login in chrome and firfox but still no use
Please check it out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIdK3.jpg)

Comment: Can you try to clear your cache and delete all cookies from your browsers?

Comment: yes i did but still i cant access

Comment: try to remove echo and print statement before header.

Comment: i sorry but can you be more specific , coz i dont know much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP & Wordpress: headers already sent - what to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285608/php-wordpress-headers-already-sent-what-to-do)

Answer (score 1):

Look like you have an empty line or blank white space in category-template.php before `<?php`

remove all blank white spaces before `<?php` and try again.

Comment: i checked but there isn't any spaces

Comment: Have you recently updated or added any plugin? if yes remove it then try.

Comment: i tried renaming the plugin folder(plugins deactivate) but didn't worked. the last thing i did was posting an article in my blog and it was working properly then

Comment: check your wp-config.php file, there should not be blank space before `<?php` and after `?>`

Comment: Or you need to double check the category-template.php for blank spaces. There should be some blank spaces

Comment: i looked at it there isnt any space before <?php but there is no ?> tag

Comment: i founf the blank space and corrected it . now another  file is showing

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/abadhote/public_html/blog/wp-includes/functions.wp-styles.php:1) in /home/abadhote/public_html/blog/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207

but i cheked tat file  but i didnt find  the spaces